# Remove green triangle in excel with 13 numbers using winnovative vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, openxml, closedxml

I'm using

to create an MS/Excel spreadsheet file. other columns has 13 digits, Excel displays those cells with a small green triangle in the corner, along with the warning that "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe".

I am using visual studio vb.net
this is my code

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports ClosedXML.Excel
If newDt.Rows.Count >= 0 Then
Dim wsColumns = wb.Worksheets.Add(newDt, worksheetname)
wsColumns.Worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents()
wsColumns.Tables.FirstOrDefault().Theme = XLTableTheme.None
wsColumns.Tables.FirstOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = False
End If
```

I want to remove the green indicator.

I tried winnovative library it doesn't have the solution either.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant column in your data table is of string type. You'll have to convert that data column to a numeric type first.

Comment: Thank you. i had it working using OpenXML.